# mysql using between to find data between now and one year in the future

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

trying to create a query which will output data from a table if one of the columns' date is within the current date and one year in the future.

so far I have something like this

```
SELECT 
    col1,`date`,col3
    FROM `session`
    WHERE
    `date`
    BETWEEN 
    (`date`(CURRENT_DATE()) AND (`date`(CURRENT_DATE()year, + 1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    col1,`date`,col3
    FROM `session`
    WHERE
    `date` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
```

`CURDATE()` and `CURRENT_DATE()` are similar. You can also just type `CURRENT_DATE` without `()`. And add `+ INTERVAL 1 YEAR` to get date of 1 year ahead.